# using ngnix infront of node.js

Tags: nginx, node.js

I am using `ngnix` infront of 4 instances of `node.js` apps running on **1** machine (quad core)

Can any **ngnix** experts give me any advice on how to configure this to get the most out of the web app.

I am using `connect/express` frameworks on node and I think they allow smart caching etc, **but** I am not sure which bits to let `ngnix` do and which **bits** to let the frameworks handle. Any guidance on getting the most out of this setup will be a great help, thanks.

Comment: interesting setup. take a look at deftserver.org if you are interested in some nginx/node.js performance benchmarking

Comment: Got a feeling defserver is going to be popular with the Java community. Looks impressive.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take into account that any one Node instance will use several threads, and will probably keep at least one thread occupied with I/O. So say that you run 4 instances on a quad core, that means that all 4 instances will produce blocking threads, meaning that you have at least 4 blocking threads (if you have a busy server) meaning that you will at some point block all activity for short periods.

I would suggest not starting more than (number of cores)-1 instances of Node, to be half sure that at least something always keeps moving.

I do assume that there is one blocking thread per Node instance, but I could be wrong. There could be more. But the point remains the same. The more "free" threads you start, the more "blocking" threads will be created as well.

Comment: Interesting, I am now thinking of going down to one instance then. The web app has nothing blocking as far as I can see. As I have other stuff running on the server (being a cheapskate) like mongodb and redis. I may even need ffmpeg or some such later.  Do you think 1 behind ngnix ok? Would you considen dropping nginx altogether?

Comment: i haven't used connect or express so i can't say what it can or cannot do compared to nginx.